# SQL expression in oracle data integrator

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, expression, oracle-data-integrator

‎ 
I have the following interface in Oracle Data Integrator

http://i44.tinypic.com/2mrsmxt.png

It execute successfully before inserting the following SQL expression

In the mapping I insert the following SQL expression to get the average when the quantity is 0

```
AVG(
    CASE WHEN TEST.QUN = 0 THEN  
        (SELECT TEST.QUN 
         FROM TEST
         WHERE TEST1.PRUDU=TEST.PRUDU
         AND TEST1.FLOW=TEST.UNIT
        AND TEST1.UNIT=TEST.UNIT
        AND to_char(TEST.DATEDDD,'MON')= to_char(TEST1.DATEDDD,'MON')
        AND TEST1.DATEDDD !=TEST.DATEDDD
        GROUP BY TEST.QUN )
 ELSE TEST.QUN
END)
```

When I check this expression in ODI the SQL expression is correct for this RDBMS  but when I executed the interface I get this error

```
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

any idea?

Comment: ODI is a specialist tool.  You might be better off asking this question on the Oracle TechNet forum dedicated to it.  [Find it here](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/business_intelligence/system_management_and_integration/data_integrator)

Comment: thanks, I just did ! hoping to get answer to to the sql error